# How to fix 411 Length Required error with file_get_contents and the expedia XML API?

Tags: php, xml, api, http

I am doing the online hotel booking using xml api(php) project.When i am working in the reservation code it shows error of the following

> `"Warning: file_get_contents(https://...@gmail.com</email><firstName>test</firstName><lastName>smith</lastName><homePhone>8870606867</homePhone><creditCardType>CA</creditCardType><creditCardNumber>5401999999999999</creditCardNumber>....</HotelRoomReservationRequest>) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required"`

its my code

```
$context  = stream_context_create(
                array(
                    'http' => array(
                        'method' => 'POST',
                        'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        "Accept: application/xml"
                    )
                )
            );
$url ='https://book.api.ean.com/....';
$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

It's for sending credit information plz kindly give me suggestion what type of error... .

Comment: You have an error the way you set the stream context options.

Comment: stackoverflow not allow to post code .i already give enough code

Answer (score 6):

As per [RFC2616 10.4.12](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.12):

```
10.4.12 411 Length Required

   The server refuses to accept the request without a defined Content-
   Length. The client MAY repeat the request if it adds a valid
   Content-Length header field containing the length of the message-body
   in the request message.
```

You need to add the `Content-Length` header to your `POST` request. That's the size in bytes (octets) of your POST request body. To obtain the length you could use `strlen` on the POST body. As your code example does not show any POST body, it's hard to give a concrete example. The post body is passed with the `['http']['content']` entry in the stream context.

Probably it's already enough if you set the [`content` entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.content) (see [*HTTP context options<sup>­Docs</sup>*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php)).

**Edit:** The following example code *might* solve your issue. It demonstrates how to send some XML to a server via a POST request using `file_get_contents` and setting headers including the `Content-Length` header.

```
$url = 'https://api.example.com/action';
$requestXML = '<xml><!-- ... the xml you want to post to the server... --></xml>';
$requestHeaders = array(
    'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept: application/xml',
    sprintf('Content-Length: %d', strlen($requestXML));
);

$context = stream_context_create(
                array(
                    'http' => array(
                        'method'  => 'POST',
                        'header'  => implode("\r\n", $requestHeaders),
                        'content' => $requestXML,
                    )
                )
            );
$responseXML = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

if (FALSE === $responseXML)
{
    throw new RuntimeException('HTTP request failed.');
}
```

If you need better error control, see the [`ignore_errors` HTTP context option<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php#context.http.ignore-errors) and [`$http_response_header`<sup>*­Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php). Detailed handling of HTTP response headers is available in a blog post of mine: [HEAD first with PHP Streams](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/head-first-with-php-streams/).

Comment: how to do content length for my code plz help me

Comment: @user1117625: Well you need to change your code, it is incomplete and I can't execute it, so I can't reproduce. Sorry.

Comment: Did you even read what hakre wrote? `Content-Length` was mentioned 2 times (and even colored for your sake). It doesn't take a genius to figure out what to do and where to put it. Do people really put no effort into trying to figure out solutions these days?

Comment: $url ='https://book.api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/res?......      $str=strlen($url);
 $context  = stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method' => 'POST','header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept:application/xml",'Content-Length:$str'))); is my code correct check it

Comment: is it correct code?stream_context_create(array('http' => array('method' => 'POST','header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept:application/xml",'Content-Length:$str')));

Comment: any one help me for this code