# PHP, How to POST a file content as json?

Tags: php, json, post

I have this php code, and it works, but the contents of `request.json` are being posted as a string encapsulating the file contents.

I want it to be posted the file contents directly (a text file containing json).   How do I need to change this code so that `$payload` not being re-encapsulated as a string before sending?

I am guessing my `'content' => json_encode( $payload )` line needs to change, but do not know PHP enough to know how to change it.

```
$url = 'http://api.phantomjscloud.com/examples/helpers/requestdata';
$payload = file_get_contents ( 'request.json' );

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/json\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode( $payload )
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if ($result === FALSE) { /* Handle error */ }

var_dump($result);
```

PS: I don't want to use 3rd party libraries like curl or zend.   Just Php!

***EDIT 1***:  clarification for those complaining json is just text.

***EDIT 2***:

when trying either
`'content' => json_decode( $payload )`

I get the error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.phantomjscloud.com/examples/helpers/requestdata): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required
 in request.php on line 15
bool(false)
```

my request.json contents are simple, if that matters:

```
{
    "hi":"world"
}
```

***EDIT 3***:

@Nasreddine answer is right.
my `request.json` file wasn't actually correct json (i didn't encapsulate the keys in double-quotes)  so I was getting a http-response error for bad json posted.

thank you, my bad :(

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense. [There is no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). JSON is a text based data format. HTTP is a protocol for transferring text. Converting an object to a string of JSON and then including it in the request body is how you make a JSON request with HTTP.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, the problem is that the string from request.json is being escaped as json again, so it's sending a string of the file contents, not the file contents directly

Comment: You need to send a `Content-Length` header according to the HTTP response code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412650/how-to-fix-411-length-required-error-with-file-get-contents-and-the-expedia-xml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're re-encoding what is already json as a json text. So instead of this:

```
'content' => json_encode( $payload )
```

Use this:

```
'content' => $payload
```

Comment: @JasonS glad I could help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`'content' => $payload`

Eventually this:

`'content' => json_decode( $payload )`

Comment: this doesn't work unfortuantely.  I think it would if my file was encapsulated in a string though.   The solution is Nasreddine's.  thank you

Comment: Well.... I also said what Nasreddine `'content' => $payload`. I do not understand why you can not see that in my answer.... Never mind...