# Post request with file_get_content not working

Tags: php, post, token, file-get-contents

I am trying to use file_get_contents to "post" to a url and get auth token. The problem I am having is that it returns a error.

`Message: file_get_contents(something): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required.`

I am not sure what is causing this but need help. Here is the function.

```
public function ForToken(){
        $username = 'gettoken';
        $password = 'something';
        $url = 'https://something.com';
        $context = stream_context_create(array (
            'http' => array (
            'header' => 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("$username:$password"),
             'method' => 'POST'
            )
        ));

        $token = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        if(token){
            var_dump($token);
        }else{
            return $resultArray['result'] = 'getting token failed';
        }
    }
```

I tried it with POSTMAN, and it works, so only problem I am having is that why isnt it working with file_get_contents.

Comment: Something must be messed up with your `$context` and `Content-Length` header is missing.

Comment: @patryk-uszynski How can I add the Content-Length?

Comment: 'file_get_content' has some limitations. Try with CURL

Comment: @RaviKumar can you give me a example with CURL please?

Comment: @RaviKumar I'm pretty sure that PHP streams can handle HTTP just fine. Curl will just make it more cumbersome.

Answer (score 3):

Cannot command so i will do it this way. If you use Postman why don't you let Postman generate the code for you. In postman you can click code at a request and you can even select in what coding language you wanne have it. Like PHP with cURL:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://somthing.com/",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "password: somthing",
    "username: gettoken"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: getting this error
cURL Error #:SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Comment: Put in this line of code in the curl_setop_array    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,

Comment: A new error now

HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.

Comment: The problem is that there must be a Content-length given with the header. Some Google searches and you must find the answer for the http error 411

Answer (score 0):

I can not comment because of my reputation;

In some servers file_get_content is not available...

You may try with CURL like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)

Comment: took your advice, tried it out with CURL but returns false all the time..

Comment: Can you post the CURL code to the main post for future reference ?

Answer (score 0):

Your request havent any data and content length is missing.

You can try this:

```
public function ForToken(){
    $username = 'gettoken';
    $password = 'something';
    $url = 'https://something.com';

    $data = array('foo' => 'some data');
    $data = http_build_query($data);

    $context_options = array (
    'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
            . "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password") . "\r\n"
            . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
        'content' => $data
        )
    );

    $context = context_create_stream($context_options);

    $token = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    if(token){
        var_dump($token);
    }else{
        return $resultArray['result'] = 'getting token failed';
    }
}
```

Here is similar problem:

[How to fix 411 Length Required error with file_get_contents and the expedia XML API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9412650/how-to-fix-411-length-required-error-with-file-get-contents-and-the-expedia-xml)

Comment: Where does the username and password goes?

Comment: @Masnad Nihit same as before. You must concat them into headers string and separate with `\r\n`

Comment: I am trying your example but failing, could you please update your example but adding my information.

Comment: Why do we need the 'content' => data?

Comment: @Masnad Nihit im not sure if it is needed. You can test it by yourself. Simply remove the data and try with `Content-Length: 0`

Answer (score 0):

RFC2616 10.4.12
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.12

Code: (Doesn't work, see below)

```
public function ForToken(){
$username = 'gettoken';
$password = 'something';
$url = 'https://something.com';
$context = stream_context_create(array (
'http' => array (
'header' => 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("$username:$password") . 'Content-Length: ' . strlen($url) . '\r\n',
'method' => 'POST'
)
));
$token = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if(token){
var_dump($token);
}else{
return $resultArray['result'] = 'getting token failed';
}
}
```

2nd Try:

```
public function ForToken(){
$username = 'gettoken';
$password = 'something';
$url = 'https://something.com';
$context_options = array (
'http' => array (
'method' => 'POST',
'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n" . "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password") . "Content-Length: " . strlen($url) . "\r\n",
'content' => $url
)
);
$context = stream_context_create($context_options);
$token = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
if(token){
var_dump($token);
}else{
return $resultArray['result'] = 'getting token failed';
}
}
```

This is from patryk-uszynski's answer formatted with the OP's code.

Comment: My double quotes I think are the problem

Comment: Double quotes for Content-Length?

Comment: Dang it, I'm doing this on my phone lol so I can't do any testing. What is the error? Is it the same error?

Comment: I put up a new version with patryk-uszynski's code. Does that work for you? It reads like it should work.

Comment: Call to undefined function context_create_stream() , is this wrong?

Comment: Dang, I also just noticed I left out the 'Authorization' header, did u fix that on your end?

Comment: The content type header should fill in what that error is referring to...Are u sure that is in your code?

Comment: Yup, trust me I did it exactly as we talked about.
I was so frustrated with this methods that I just used PEAR HTTPS2 Request and it works fine now, I guess I dont want to use filegetcontent or curl.... Its pretty annoying at this moment

Comment: Well as long as it's working. You should post your solution and mark it as an answer.

Comment: Yea I Will do that, Thanks for all the Help.
Sorry for some reason this was not working and I was under a deadline so I didnt want to put more time into this.